# How can I open port with wildcard?

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes

I am going to install kubernetes on my VPS servers. The VPS servers based on Ubuntu 18.04 server and I am using [Uncomplicated Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncomplicated_Firewall).

I have to [open several ports](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#check-required-ports) on Ubuntu server, but one of them is marked with a wildcard:

```
TCP    Inbound    6443*    Kubernetes API server    All
```

How can I open a port with a wildcard? Would the following be correct?

```
sudo ufw allow 6443*
```

Comment: The * is a note for "Any port numbers marked with * are overridable, so you will need to ensure any custom ports you provide are also open.".  Just use 6443 unless the installation is customised

Comment: Was this enough? Did you managed to conclude your configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wildcard `*` in this case means that it could be **any port** that fits your needs (except, of course, ports already in use or reserved).

[In documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#check-required-ports):

> Any port numbers marked with `*` are overridable, so you will need to ensure any custom ports you provide are also open.

Open the port with: `sudo ufw allow 6443` and you are good to go.

---

Also related to this question, UWF *does not accept* the wildcard for rules.

- You can specify one port: `ufw allow 6443`
- You can specify the service: `uwf allow ftp`
- You can specify a range: `ufw allow 1234:5678/tcp`